# Cookie Aware WebClient - How to handle expiry

Tags: c#, webclient

Firstly, apologies for my ignorance in this area.

I am attempting to use the WebClient to access a 3rd party API.

There is a login function, which when called, returns 4 cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=98F22A67FD25F41898F39756FEBB5D8D; Path=/
Set-Cookie: BI=D9022C3F4AE74A64B3350DD7A3C9AC17; Expires=Sat, 05-Oct-2024 13:37:55 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: LNG=en__NET; Expires=Sat, 05-Oct-2024 13:37:55 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerPOOL-94.236.111.248-443=308586688.36895.0000; path=/
```

I have used the information on this page to override the WebClient and make it "Cookie Aware" using the information on this page http://couldbedone.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html

My problem is that, these cookies have to be sent with every subsequent request to the API.

At the moment I have managed to get it working by creating the cookie aware Webclient, logging in, and then using the same WebClient instance to make another call. But this means that every time I make a call I am first making a "login" call as well.

What is the best practice to work out if the cookie has expired? Do I need to pull it out as a string and extract the date and work it out from there? Or is there a better way?

Also, for the life of me, I cannot seem to find how to pull the value of the "cookies"?

Any guidance would be very much appreciated?

Thanks

Trev